# Disable/turn off visual styles/theming for just a single form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-styles

I have a winforms application. Main form has some buttons that open other forms on click.

There is a form I would like to disable visual styles/theme. Also I would like to disable visual styles for its childs. Is it possible? If so how?

For example, suppose I have three buttons on main form:

- `Button1` opens `form1` on click
- `Button2` opens `form2` on click
- `Button3` opens `form3` on click

so when I click `Button2` I would like to only disable visual styles on it but I would like to keep visual styles enabled for forms: `form1` and `form3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [PInvoke SetWindowTheme](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/uxtheme.setwindowtheme):

```
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appname, string idlist);
```

Then for example in your `button2` event handler:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
SetWindowTheme(form2.Handle, "", "");
form2.Show();
```

Comment: I think it supports only "Windows Vista [desktop apps only]".. Could you please check here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @pavanc It looks like it says vista is a minimum requirement

Comment: @Bassie Is it compatible with .NET Framework 1.1? and If I would like to disable visual styles for entire application how I should proceed?