# Remove Visual Effects on Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way to remove any visual effects of inno setup installer so it looks like a window 95 skin?

[image]

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images! :) Use PNG instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the picture you shown is from an installer with turned off **Styles** settings in Windows.

See this forum: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/127339-visual-styles-windows-buttons-turn-off.html if you are interested in such solution.

To achieve that design for your Inno Setup installer you can **create your own style** that mimic the Win95 style and apply it to your installer using VCL Styles plugin.

See https://theroadtodelphi.com/2013/12/11/vcl-styles-for-inno-setup/

Comment: I know I can disable windows styles and I know I can design a VCL style myself, but I want to know if possible forcing the setup itself to disable visual styles for itself...

Comment: I am sorry, after some research I did not found a way how to turn off styles for selected app in Windows. Using the custom VCL style is probably better.

Comment: what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193419/disable-turn-off-visual-styles-theming-for-just-a-single-form

Comment: or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298486/how-do-i-disable-visual-styles-for-just-one-control-and-not-its-children
how to use with inno setup? possible?

Comment: That is a per-form solution, but it could work (I did not try it) also for the installer, thanks for finding this out.

Comment: how to implement such this in inno setup? I'm not familiar with Delphi or pascal

Comment: That is a C sharp code, the best is to create a .dll plugin and use it from installer.see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776847/returning-a-string-from-a-c-sharp-dll-with-unmanaged-exports-to-inno-setup-scrip

Comment: that c# code is using an external dll, then calling a method from that dll. So Do you think in inno setup is it possible to call a dll method?

Comment: Yes, Inno Setup can load Dll and call its methods, see the link I posted.